# Python の簡易webサーバを起動しようとすると "python.exe は、実行中の Windows のバージョンと互換性がありません。"

Tags: python, windows

Pythonで簡単なウェブアプリを作ろうと、コマンドプロンプトから `python -m http.server --cig`と実行して簡易ウェブサーバーを立ち上げようとしたのですが、"サポートされてない16ビットのアプリケーション" というダイアログが表示され実行できませんでした。

コードを実行すると以下のようになってしまいます。

```
C:\Users\masao>python -m http.server --cgi 8080
C:\Users\masao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe は、実行中の Windows のバージョンと互換性がありません。コンピューターのシステム情報を確認してから、ソフトウェアの発行元に問い合わせてください 。
```

対処の仕方を教えてください。

**実行環境:**
Windows (64bit版)、Python も公式サイトから Windows 向けの 64bit 版のインストーラをダウンロードしています。

Comment: 実行時の引数が`-cig`ではなく`-cgi`の間違いでありませんか？それでも動かなければ、実際に試しているコードを質問文に追記してみてください。

Comment: pythonをどのようにインストールしたのかに原因がありそうですので、インストール手順を提示してください。

Comment: 公式サイトからwindowsの64ビットのインストーラーをダウンロードし、実行しました。

Comment: お使いのPCは64bitの環境でしょうか？

Comment: はい、64ビットのpc環境です。

Comment: where python の結果などわかります？Linuxならwhich python